# SQL Primary Key Duplicate Values

Tags: sql, database, duplicates, primary-key

I have a table with 2 primary key columns : `ID` and `StudentID`.

`ID` column is set to `isIdentity =  Yes` with auto increment.

I've tested it multiple times before, but for some reason this time, when I insert a duplicate value on `StudentID`, it does not throw the error but instead added it on to the database. 2 of the same values are displayed when I show the table data.

What can be the problem here?

Comment: Can you share your actual table declaration?  It sounds like you have not specified that StudentID is the one primary key.  If you really need two unique columns you can make one the primary key and create a unique index on the other.

Comment: Hello, here is a screenshot of the table : http://prntscr.com/at6grl

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a compound primary key on `ID` and `StudentID`.  That means you the combination of ID and StudentID together must be unique.  Since `ID` is an identity column that combination of `ID` and `StudentID` will always be unique (because `ID` is already unique on its own).

You can change the primary key to be on `ID` only.  Then you can add a unique index on `StudentID`.  For example:

```
create unique index idx_studentID on yourTable(StudentID)
```

That will insure that the StudentID column, in fact, contains only unique values.

It seems like you may not actually need `ID` column, but that's a little wider discussion than your original question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and I also want to ask , can unique index be used as a foreign key on another table?

Comment: Thanks, I followed your solution and it works fine, throws an error on a duplicate value as expected, thank you!

Comment: A unique index itself is not related to a foreign key.  In your case you can use `StudentID` in a unique index and simultaneously use it in a foreign key.  You'd add it something like this: `ALTER TABLE yourTable
ADD FOREIGN KEY (StudentID)
REFERENCES parentTable(StudentID)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have 2 "primary keys". You can have a *compound* primary key (meaning the *combination* needs to be unique, which is what it sounds like you have now.  Or, You can have one "primary" key and one "unique" constraint which is what it sounds like you *want*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, will set the changes and see how it goes now

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have 2 Primary Keys. You can have multiple Unique Keys if needed, which should help you in your case. Make sure to go back to your table creation and double check which column is your Primary Key and work from there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so set 1 primary key and the other a unique key. I also want to ask what characteristics the primary key has from a unique key, do they work the as the same ( does not allow duplicate values) or is there more to it?

Answer (score 0):

Do not mix up identity, primary key and unique key.

1. Any table can have identity key which you can setup on table. Here seed can be say 1, then increment it by 1. So incremental order will like 1,2,3...and so on.
2. Primary key, one can define on specific column of the table. Identity key can be used as primary key. But you can have identity column as well primary key on same table. Primary key is one and only for the table.So if you are treating identity as primary key, then you will have no further table column as primary key.
3. Unique key, can be more than one column with your table.

While fetching rows from table data, if you provide combination of identity key, primary key and unique key then search will be fastest

Comment: Right, so i can remove the primary key on the Identity key, and just set the primary key for studentID?

Answer (score 0):

During my first response, I have mentioned that one can generate identity column by soft coding and it will not be treated as primary key.Following is syntax one can use while creating table.

1] If one wish to set identity column as primary key
--id int identity(1,1) primary key
2] If one doesn't wish to set identity column as primary key and still wish
to us identity column then donot us word primary key for identity column.
--id int identity(1,1) 
In this 2] case scenario, one may create primary key on other table column.